# Connect bus wires to various ports of a channelized subsheet

Tags: altium, bus

I have an 8-line bus `chselect[7..0]`.
I also have a 4x repeated subsheet, each of which has two inputs `CSAb` and `CSBb`.
Denote these inputs as `CSAb_0, CSBb_0, CSAb_1, CSBb_1,...,CSBb_3` where the number after the underscore indicates which instance the instance of the repeated subsheet.

I want to connect the bus like this:

```
chselect[0] --> CSAb_0
chselect[1] --> CSBb_0

chselect[2] --> CSAb_1
chselect[3] --> CSBb_1

chselect[4] --> CSAb_2
chselect[5] --> CSBb_2

chselect[6] --> CSAb_3
chselect[7] --> CSBb_3
```

Here's my attempt in Altium

[image]

Is this correct and/or in line with best practice?

I have also asked this on the [Altium forum](https://forum.live.altium.com/posts/220453).

Comment: Without having time to go into Altium _right now_ I suspect it'll be a lot easier on you if you can regroup it so all CSA can be [0..3] on chselect and CSB on [4..7]. If possible.

Answer (score 1):

An approach that works:

Inside `digital_interface.SchDoc`, group the pins as shown in Figure 1.

[image]
**Figure 1:** Digital pins grouped into two busses. Each bus will be connected to one input of the channelized block.

Then, in the top level sheet, just use standard channelization as shown in Figure 2.

[image]
**Figure 2:** The `CSAb` and `CSBb` busses are channelized in the usual way.

This isn't as elegant as I'd like, but it works.